# iOS Agent build failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

We are trying to build https://github.com/wso2/emm-agent-ios app using XCode 6.3.2.

In order to avoid issues with libOHTTPStubs library I have changed the following projects settings:

- Architectures: i386
- Build active architecture only: NO

Then I prepared an app ID on Apple Developer portal, configured Push notifications using the same CertificateSigningRequest as I prepared following your instructions at https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Client+Configurations
I also prepared an Enterprise In House Provisioning profile and successfully archived the app.
Problem is I can’t export it for In House or anything else, Xcode says “The archive contains nothing that can be signed”

Answer (score 0):

Your architectures have to include arm64, since i386 is only for the simulator.  If you can build and run the code on an iPhone or iPad you should be able to export it.